# How can make a form for redirecting user to the entered address in Django?

Tags: django

I am a little confused as to how should I be working on making a simple form that takes a website url input from a user and redirects on clicking the submit form button. Should I be using the UserCreationForm , if so , what fields should I be using for the same. Or should I be creating a custom form for the same .

Comment: Why should it be a `UserCreationForm`? If there is only going to be a single field even using a form sounds overkill if you ask me. Just POST the URL to a function based view and return a `redirect()`.

Comment: I want to add some more authentication fields as well, just for the sake of it . But yeah thanks using a function based view sounds like a correct path.

Comment: I would recommend leaving the authentication to Django and simply require the user to be logged in. See my answer for a simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a text field then you should avoid forms. Create a normal HTML form with a input type text and get that value in backend.

HTML: mytemplate.html

```html
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="url" name="url" placeholder="https://example.com" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def redirect_to_url(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        url = request.POST.get('url')
        return redirect(url)
    else:
        return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {})
```

This is a very basic implementation. You can also verify if the url exists.

```py
import requests
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def redirect_to_url(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        url = request.POST.get('url')
        resp = requests.get(url)
        if resp.status_code == 200:    # some other validation and conditions
            return redirect(url)
        return HttpResponse('Invalid URL')
    else:
        return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {})
```

For more about [input type url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url) and Django [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Comment: Adding small details like requests to this form has taught me more about Django . Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (simplified) example:

Template:

```
<form action="{% url 'my_view' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="url" type="url">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

View:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect(request.POST.get("url"))
    else:
        return render(request, "my_template.html")
```